# Postgresql - Looping through array_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table from which I need to calculate the number of times `intent_level` changes for each `id`.

**Sample Table format :**

```
id | start_time | intent_level
----+------------+--------------
 1  | 2          | status
 1  | 3          | status
 1  | 1          |
 1  | 4          | category
 2  | 5          | status
 2  | 8          |
 2  | 7          | status
```

I couldn't figure out how to loop through `array_agg` and compare consecutive elements. Below I tried using `array_agg`, but then I don't know how to loop through it and compare consecutive elements.

```
select 
id, 
array_agg (intent_level ORDER BY start_time)
FROM temp.chats
GROUP BY id;
```

which gives output :

```
id |          array_agg
----+-----------------------------
 1  | {"",status,status,category}
 2  | {status,status,""}
```

**Desired output is :**

```
id |          array_agg
----+-----------------------------
 1  | 2
 2  | 1
```

2 (since value changes from `"" to status`(1 to 2) and `status to category`(3 to 4))

1 (since value changes from `status to ""`(2 to 3))

*CREATE AND INSERT QUERIES :*

```
create table temp.chats (
    id varchar(5),
    start_time varchar(5),
    intent_level varchar(20)
);

insert into temp.chats values 
('1', '2', 'status'),
('1', '3', 'status'),
('1', '1', ''),
('1', '4', 'category'),
('2', '5', 'status'),
('2', '8', ''),
('2', '7', 'status');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` and aggregate:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select c.*,
             lag(intent_level) over (partition by id order by start_time) as prev_intent_level
      from temp.chats c
     ) c
where prev_intent_level is distinct from intent_level
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=55efb6a974b7bbae830cf71bf0fc1f35) is a db<>fiddle.

Arrays seem quite unnecessary for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the result should be `2` and `1` right? Your query gives `3` and `2`.

Comment: Since `LAG()` function allows us to access previous row from the given row, I guess the query is comparing the first element with something, which it shouldn't. Also should we use the `(partition by id order by start_time)` block for intent_level also, so that it's ordered according to the start_time.

Comment: Use `lag(intent_level, 1, intent_level)` to exclude first row in a group from the changes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff and @Serg.